# How to replace entered characters in any application?

Tags: android, input, proxy, textedit

My goal/problem: 
I want to write android application that allows user to replace some characters to another in input text. This application should work with all existing apps.

Example:
When I write text message I want to have possibility to replace all polish diacritics to their   equivalents (ó to o, ż to z, ś to s and so on).
My solutions:

Poor but feasible:

- I write text in my application then copy text and paste in text message application. But it is quite inconvenient due to this copying.
- I  write text already in destination application the copy all text to clipboard and paste it back. I have application running in background to handle clipboard that changes this text. Also quite inconvenient.

Better but I am not sure if possible:

- I write some kind of proxy to InputMethodService and when user write text using software keyboard with this proxy he gets modified text back. Is it possible to write something like that?

Best:

- I add some option to TextView object. When I long tap on any textview I get menu that allows to select InputMethod (change software keyboard) and edit text (copy, mark, paste etc.) Is there way to add my option say "replace characters" to this menu?

Again I don't want this to work only within my application but with all installed application.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your own keyboard. Check the samples for the SoftKeyboard example that comes with the SDK. The user can then enable your keyboard and will be able to use it in all apps.

Comment: Yes but writing my own keyboard seems to me to be quite big task. Also users rather won't easily change their current keyboards. Even I use swype and don't want to change that.

Comment: You can start with the Android OSP keyboard (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) and modify from there. It includes swype-like functionality as of a recent version.

Comment: Ok, this is one way to do this, but again: user will have to change his current keyboard which kind of unacceptable for me. I need my solution to be fully independent from the software keyboard.